# GitHub actions - concurrency between different repositories

Tags: locking, github-actions, global

Would anyone of you if it's possible to set up concurrency between different repositories (on the org level) in GitHub Actions?

**Problem:**
Microservices from different repositories are tested on the same k8s cluster. I'd like to ensure that only one GitHub Action will use this cluster.

**Documentation:**
This is not explained in the documentation for this feature: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-concurrency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open AI suggested a slightly different approach.

[image]